# Test of significance on time series data/event study - Paired sample t test or cross correlation or something else?

Tags: time-series, correlation, statistical-significance, econometrics, autocorrelation

Suppose I have weekly sales data for two companies (A and B) which can be considered to be substitutes of each other. They have same internal policies, same products, have same sales trends, and operate in the same environment etc. Though the average sales of company A is greater than company B.

Company B introduces a policy change at t=0. I have weekly sales data of both companies from -50 weeks to +20 weeks relative to t=0.

I can compute **the impact** of the policy change on the sales of company B by calculating difference between

- the expected sales of company B calculated using the expected growth rates (i.e week over week growth rate of sales of company A)
- and the actual sales of company B after t=0

Now my main question is to test the significance of **the impact** thus calculated.

I am not sure if I can use a paired sample t test as the means of sales are  different. Company A is larger than company B thus has greater sales.

Cross Correlation also doesn't seem to make sense.